# Media Streaming Help AWS Cloudfront HLS RTMP

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

Would really appreciate some help with the following I have been working with AWS for a while now to try and deliver a secure streaming experience but I seem to hit a hurdle at every step. I am just going to list them all some are really obvious.

Take the following.

1. **Progressive streaming grabbing the public URLs via Amazon S3 and streaming**.
   (hurdle: user can just right click on most players and download, or open web inspector click network refresh the page and grab the URL).
2. **Signing the URLs with one of the SDKs**

   `$signedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl($bucket, 'video.mp4', '+10 minutes');`

(hurdle: makes no real difference to the above the user can still copy the URL in web inspector network tab and download)

3. **Using CloudFront RTMP and Amazon S3**
   (hurdle: works great for browser streaming relying on Flash and there is no way to grab the URL through inspect element and download, but this does need a fallback for mobile in which a MP4 would be needed to be provided you can open safari web developer tool set user agent to iPhone refresh and get the URL to download)
4. **Using HLS streaming**
   (hurdle: works great on the browser and mobile but I hear it is not supported on some android devices, after playing around with this and creating a playlist I need to make all my segments public so someone could download each segment and then merge together I know i am being super picky now) demo from amazon here https://edgereinvent.com/hls I understand it would take someone ages to do this and it is probably not worth it so this would be the best option.

I know this is possible because other people manage it I think the best way is to use the HLS method and make the `playlist.m3ub8` file signed with a real short time but if some can access the `m3ub8` they can paste it into a service like this http://www.flashls.org/mediaelement/demo/mediaelementplayer-hls.html and then view the video.

I know there is DRM which I am going to look into now, I just need to make my output files/segments encrypted within the web inspect element so they cannot be clicked this should solve a lot of my problems but cant find any good step by step tutorials on how to do this.

Can anyone give advise on their experiences?

Thanks

Update picture of netflix's encrypted .ts files this is what i need to figure out.
[image]

Comment: Any solution that you come up with is not going to be 'secure'.  For an end-user to be able to play a video they must be getting that video data on their local computer/phone or else it wouldn't work.  Meaning they can always save it some how.  At best you are looking for a solution to make it difficult for basic users to save your content.    You need to balance how many users you are going to lose or exclude with your "security" methods vs how many pirates are going to "steal" the content that you put on their computers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement AES-128 encryption to HLS.

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?437-How-to-secure-Apple-HLS-streaming-using-DRM-encryption

Actually it is a challenge, but will try explain in short:

I do not know details of your project, but you will need make a converter script (probably python or bash https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-June/022049.html that will use ffmpeg and openssl) that will convert your mp4 to hls and make similar playlist.m3u8 and will encrypt every converted chunk with aes-128:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:107
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://yoursite.com/api/key/video_id",IV=0xeefb9948c3ce6cd377b897a9547a479d,KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1"
#EXTINF:3.069,
media-uzfvxf2u9_107.ts
#EXTINF:3.036,
media-uzfvxf2u9_108.ts
```

Where https://yoursite.com/api/key/video_id is  link that will read the key from DB and return proper key by "video_id" that was used by converter script (so converter must store used key to DB)

Also you need to implement some protection system to api that will manage access to read key. Here you can use either cookie or IP tracking.

Also if you can set cookie with your player, it is possible to use more simple solution, that Amazon announced recently https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-signed-cookies-for-private-content/

**Update:**

Actually the way, that I described, you will have encrypted .ts files   that will be possible to replay only if you will have encryption key that is provided at playlist.m3u8 via api delivery link https://yoursite.com/api/key/video_id , other way you will be able just download as digital trash.

You can use either own "converter", that I shown an example, and you can see follow line of the code:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in "$tempDir/$splitFilePrefix"$i.ts \
-out "$outDir/$splitFilePrefix"$i.ts -nosalt -iv $initializationVector -K $encryptionKey
```

So it will make encrypted .ts chunks

Or you can easy use AWS elastic transcoder, that will give you ready-to-go solution for content converting, but you will need pay ещ Amazon for it usage, base on http://aws.amazon.com/ru/elastictranscoder/pricing/

Comment: Hi Evgeniy i have just watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzeho2uLpHM which explains AES encryption and it is easy to implement with the elastic transcoder but within the example i was still able to download the .ts files. I know it is possible because Netflix uses AWS and after being at their recent summit i understand everything is interchangeable so if Netflix are doing it i should be able to do it in theory. I have updated my post with a picture of Netflix's .ts files they can be downloaded but they are useless this is the process i need just missing that step.

Comment: Seems you misunderstand my post, will make update with more explaintations

Comment: Hi Evgeniy thanks i think this has helped as well http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430261-aes-content-protection